# Threading in a complex application which uses Popen, Serial and MQTT

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am creating a `python3` module which takes into consideration:

1. MQTT Library from `paho.mqtt.client`
2. Reading GPS data and parsing using `pynmea2 and serial`
3. reading particular information from `Popen and PIPE` subprocesses
4. reading/writing application to `InfluxDB`

#### structure

```
.
|-- myApp
|   |-- mqtt
|   |-- db
|   |-- gps
|   |-- n2k
|-- main.py
```

In `mqtt` I have created a wrapper class for the `mqtt.Client` where in the above mentioned `main.py` one needs to only use:

```
  client = myMqtt()
  client.run() # <--- run() has `loop_forever()`
```

[`loop_forever()` code from paho.mqtt](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L1541)

for `gps` and `db` I am thinking of creating similar wrappers for my app.

For `n2k` I have a simple wrapper, which calls pre-installed binaries (`actisense-serial` and `analyzer`) on `/dev/ttyUSB0` port as follows:

```
class N2KParser:
    def __init__(self, parser=None):
        self.cfg = get_configuration('n2k') # this has all the configuration (/dev/ttyUSB0)

        self.actisense_process = Popen(['actisense-serial', '-r', self.cfg['port']], stdout=PIPE)
        self.analyzer_proc = Popen(['analyzer', '-json'], stdin=self.actisense_process.stdout,
                                    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    def read(self):
        logger.info('Reading NMEA2000 via Actisense-NGT1 Gateway')
        while self.analyzer_proc.poll() is None:
            n2k_data = self.analyzer_proc.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8')
            try:
                n2k_dict = json.loads(n2k_data)
            except Exception as e:
                raise e
                self.actisense_process.close()
                self.analyzer_proc.close()

    def close():
        logger.info('Closing the Parser for N2K')
        self.actisense_process.close()
        self.analyzer_proc.close()
```

In the `main.py` file similar to `mqtt` I add an instance of `n2k` after the `client.run()`

```
from myApp.cloud.Client import CloudMqtt
from myApp.db.dbClient import influxInstance
from myApp.nmea2k.n2kClient import N2KParser
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        db = influxInstance()
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    try:
        client = CloudMqtt()
        rc = client.run()
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
        db.close()
        client.loop_stop()
        client.disconnect()
    try:
        parser = N2KParser() # <--- this is not executed since blocked by `client.run()`
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
        parser.close()
```

As in the comment:

- since the `run()` method uses `loop_forever()` which is using Threading and is blocked forever hence the `N2KParser` is not created and called.

What is an optimal way to structure the calling of such submodules within my `myApp` so that they all run parallel without blocking each other?

#### P.S.

since I use `logging` for all the submodules: here is the output on the `stdout`

`INFO:myApp.db.dbClient:Client instance to DB created                                                                       INFO:myApp.cloud.Client:MQTT client instance created                                                                       DEBUG:myApp.cloud.Client:Sending CONNECT (u1, p1, wr0, wq0, wf0, c0, k60) client_id=b'f628a6d8-188a-403e-90ef-da72ec1474b6'DEBUG:umg.cloud.Client:Received CONNACK (1, 0)                                                                           DEBUG:myApp.cloud.Client:RC: 0                                                                                             INFO:myApp.cloud.Client:connected to cloud                                                                                 DEBUG:myApp.cloud.Client:Sending PINGREQ                                                                                     DEBUG:myApp.cloud.Client:Received PINGRESP`